# record in an array the user' inputs ocaml, syntax error for loop

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I am trying to record in an array the user' inputs
Yet it is saying me :

```
line 5, characters 0-3:
Error: Syntax error
```

I don't understand why, because the syntax of the `for` seems ok
So here is the code  :

```
let n = read_int()

let ar_of_int = Array.make n 0

for i = 0 to n - 1 do
   let b = read_int ()
   ar_of_int.(i) <- b
done
```

Comment: The syntax is `let ... in`

Comment: Why the compilator doesn't accept  ar_of_int or n to be global variable ?

Comment: @JIJOJJH there's no such thing as "global" variable in Ocaml.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an `in` after the binding part of the `let`:

```
for i = 0 to n - 1 do
   let b = read_int ()
   in ar_of_int.(i) <- b
done
```

Or even simply:

```
for i = 0 to n - 1 do
   ar_of_int.(i) <- read_int ()
done
```

Edit:

> Ok it's ok now, if I put in everywhere it works. What I don't understand is that in, means local variable, but why here the compiler doesn't accept global variable ?

This is how the language is defined. A global binding can only occur at top level, not inside expressions. Moreover, defining a global variable inside expressions would certainly be bad style.

> Thank you, but note that what you say doesn't work

There are different issues.

First if you write a file named `/tmp/foo.ml` with this content:

```
let n = read_int ()
let ar_of_int = Array.make n 0
for i = 0 to (n - 1) do
  ar_of_int.(i) <- read_int ()
done
```

... and if you load or compile it with resp. `ocaml` and `ocamlc`, you have a syntax error near `for`, because it is not preceded by a `;;` when you enter a toplevel expression:

> Outside of the toplevel, uses of ;; are, at best, infrequent and are
>   never required for well written code. Briefly, double semi-colon ;;
>   can used for three reasons:
>
> - For compatibility with the toplevel;
> - To split the code to ease debugging;
> - To introduce a toplevel expression.

[The Structure of OCaml Programs](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.html#The-disappearance-of)

However, using `;;` is discouraged, and you should use instead:

```
let n = read_int ()
let ar_of_int = Array.make n 0
let _ =
  for i = 0 to (n - 1) do
    ar_of_int.(i) <- read_int ()
  done
```

Note the use of `let` to bind `_` only for effects.

Secondly, if you *paste* the following text, with semicolons, in the toplevel, you have another error:

```
let n = read_int ();;

let ar_of_int = Array.make n 0 ;;

for i = 0 to (n - 1) do
  ar_of_int.(i) <- read_int ()
done
```

That's because each instruction is evaluated when `;;` is read, and `read_int` wants to read an integer, but the input stream contains the rest of the program. So it gets an `l` (from the next `let`), and complains about the bad input.

Comment: Ok it's ok now, if I put in everywhere it works.  What I don't understand is that in, means local variable, but why here the compilator doesn't accept global variable ?

Comment: Thank you, but note that what you say doesn't work, I have to make ar_of_int and n local variables in order to make the code works. So, it means that I can't do anything with my array after this code because it's local and hence I don't understand why I can't make it global...

Answer (score 0):

There are no "global" variables in functional programming, or at least Ocaml. In an imperative language, statements like this are normal

```
let n = read_int()
let p = n + 1
```

because `=` is an assignment, i.e. storing global states. In Ocaml, `=` is a binding. In functional programming the bounded values die when they are out of scope.

`n` and `ar_of_int` can be "global" to the child scopes.

```
let _ = 
   let n = read_int() 
   and ar_of_int = Array.make n 0 in

       for i = 0 to n - 1 do
           let b = read_int ()
           ar_of_int.(i) <- b
       done;

       if Array.length ar_of_int > 0 then
           print_int ar_of_int.(0);

           let an_int = !ar_of_int.(0) in 
               let plus_one = an_int + 1 in
                   print_int plus_one

  (** `n` doesn't exist here *)
  (** print_int n *)
```

Note that `_` function expects no returned value. The whole function itself is an expression.

You can create a module-level variables and classes and use them like global values though.